# Remove certain JSONObject keys in the toString() of a POJO

Tags: java, json, jpa, tostring

I am having an issue of removing some JSONObject keys in the `toString()` of my JPA POJO. I just do not want them to be shown in `toString()` while keeping them in POJO so that I can work with them. I could manage to remove them in the Parent entity, but I was not able to do that in child entities. Below is my `toString()` implementation in my parent entity.

```
@Entity
public class MyPoJo () {
// all fields

// getters and setters

@Override
public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JSONObject modifiedJSON = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(this));
        modifiedJSON.remove("batchId");
        return modifiedJSON.toString();
     }
}
```

I tried to do the same thing in all my child entities. When I call toString(), `batchId` is gone only in parent entity. They still exist in child ones. How can I remove some keys in child entities? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating `Json` manually in `toString()`?

Comment: Modify your child entity also to the same?

Comment: @SandeepKumar: Because I need to format the pojo as JSON as inputs to call web interfaces.

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni: I did that already but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jackson to achieve this by marking the fields to be ignored as `@JsonIgnore`.

```java
@Entity
public class MyPoJo () {
// all fields
@JsonIgnore
private String batchId;

// getters and setters

@Override
public String toString() {
        // Exception handling code not added
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
     }
}
```

You can further move `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` and expection handling code to a separate class to avoid creating new ObjectMapper object for each `toString()` call.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want. I also followed your suggestion to create a class for this purpose.
`public class PojoFormatter {
 
 public static String ConvertToApiReady (MyPojo p) throws JsonProcessingException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
 }
 
}`